# CSS Positioning of button with empty text

Tags: css, html

I have three simple html buttons styled with `height` - `min-width` - and `border`. One with text, second with non braking space, and last with empty text.

My nob problem is on browser view, the last button with empty text is printing in different place.

CSS:

```
.test {
    height: 27px;
    border: 1px solid #b4b1ff;
    min-width: 54px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<button class="test">Text</button>      <!-- with text -->
<button class="test">&nbsp;</button>    <!-- with Non Breaking Space -->
<button class="test"></button>          <!-- Empty ?? -->
```

see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/egv65/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Button elements are, I believe `inline` by default so you would need to vertically align them

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/egv65/1/)

**CSS**

```
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
.test {
    height: 27px;
    border: 1px solid #b4b1ff;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Paulie_D I din't think about vertical-align yes!

Comment: So why does the empty button break the inline flow? Looks like the OP want some explanation, not some **fix**.

Comment: Very well, because the **default** alignment for inline elements is `baseline` the empty element is attempting to aligning with the baseline ot the text. I'm sure the OP can google "baseline". :)