# How do i get a button with an image inside to line up vertically with an input box?

Tags: html, css

When I add a button next to my input it works fine unless I use a image instead of text.

```css
input {
  height:32px;
  padding: 0;
}
button {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
}
img {
  width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text"><button type="submit"><img src="https://png.pngtree.com/png-vector/20190419/ourmid/pngtree-vector-right-arrow-icon-png-image_956430.jpg"></button>
```

Comment: I'm currently on mobile so I can't check. Does the button or input have a `margin`?

Comment: @Someguy No, i don't think so

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22694296/css-positioning-of-button-with-empty-text#:~:text=Very%20well%2C%20because%20the%20default%20alignment%20for%20inline,I%27m%20sure%20the%20OP%20can%20google%20%22baseline%22.%20%3A%29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this

```css
input {
  height:32px;
  padding: 0;
}
button {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
}
img {
  width: 20px;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="text"><button type="submit"><img src="https://png.pngtree.com/png-vector/20190419/ourmid/pngtree-vector-right-arrow-icon-png-image_956430.jpg"></button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap them with a parent div, which has `display: flex;` and `align-items: center;`.